# Program crashes when run outside IDE

Tags: c++, memory, crash

I'm currently working on a C++ program in Windows XP that processes large sets of data.  Our largest input file causes the program to terminate unexpectedly with no sort of error message.  Interestingly, when the program is run from our IDE (Code::Blocks), the file is processed without any such issues.

As the data is being processed, it's placed into a tree structure.  After we finish our computations, the data is moved into a C++ STL vector before being sent off to be rendered in OpenGL.

I was hoping to gain some insight into what might be causing this crash.  I've already checked out another post which I can't post a link to since I'm a new user.  The issue in the post was quite similar to mine and resulted from an out of bounds index to an array.  However, I'm quite sure no such out-of-bounds error is occurring.

I'm wondering if, perhaps, the size of the data set is leading to issues when allocating space for the vector.  The systems I've been testing the program on should, in theory, have adequate memory to handle the data (2GB of RAM with the data set taking up approx. 1GB).  Of course, if memory serves, the STL vectors simply double their allocated space when their capacity is reached.

Thanks, Eric

Comment: When you run the app outside of the IDE do you recompile it or anything? 

Are you running the debug build?

Comment: I've tried both the debug build and the release build, both produce the same result.

Comment: what about dlls? Are you linking in dlls or anything like that? Have you tried running it via the cmd line vs the shell?

Comment: Why can't you attach the debugger to the process when the exception happens?

Comment: There are a few dlls being linked in from the GTK+ and GtkGlExt libraries.  I hadn't thought of running from the command line though...

Comment: I'm actually in the process of running it with gdb attached to the process.  Thanks for the suggestion though!  Part of the problem (and why I think it's a size issue) is that the program _only_ crashes on this file which takes approximately one hour to process.  None of our smaller input files replicate the crash.

Comment: Tough test case =/ But this will not be solved by qualified guesses. You need to catch the exception when it happens, so you can examine the call stack, variables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, our hardware is reaching its limit.  The program was hitting the system's memory limit and failing miserably.  We couldn't even see the error statements being produced until I hooked cerr into a file from the command line (thanks starko).  Thanks for all the helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 9):

The fact that the code works within the IDE (presumably running within a debugger?), but not standalone suggests to me that it might be an initialisation issue.

Comment: Some additional explanation of what you mean by initialisation issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler with the warning level set to max.

Then check all your warning. I would guess it is an uninitialized variable (that in debug mode is being initialized to NULL/0).

Personally I have set my templates so that warnings are always at max and that warnings are flagged as errors so that compilation will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably find it helpful to configure the O/S to create a crash dump (maybe, I don't know, still by using some Windows system software called "Dr Watson"), to which you can then attach a debugger after the program has crashed (assuming that it *is* crashing).

You should also trap the various ways in which a program might exit semi-gracefully without a crash dump: `atexit`, `set_unexpected`, `set_terminate` and maybe others.

Answer (score 1):

What does your memory model look like?  Are you banging up against an index limit (i.e. sizeof int)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your program is throwing an exception that you are not catching. The [boost test framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/index.html) has some exception handlers that could be a quick way to localise the exception location.

Are there indices in the tree structure that could overflow? Are you using indexes into the vector that are beyond the current size of the vector?

```
new vector...    
vector.push_back()
vector.push_back()
vector[0] = xyz
vector[1] = abc
vector[2] = slsk // Uh,oh, outside vector
```

How large is your largest input set? Do you end up allocating size*size elements? If so, is your largest input set larger than 65536 elements (65536*65536 == MAX_INT)?

I agree the most likely reason that the IDE works fine when standalone does not is because the debugger is wiping memory to 0 or using memory guards around allocated memory.

Failing anything else, is it possible to reduce the size of your data set until you find exactly the size that works, and a slightly large example that fails - that might be informative.

Comment: In theory I could pinpoint the exact size at which the error occurs, but as I mentioned in the comments to the original post, the test case is large enough so that this is unfeasible.  The data set may, in fact, be large enough to hit the integer overflow, which I've put into the queue of things to check.

Comment: If you did want to find the right size, you would do a binary search - remove half the data, put a quarter back in, remove 1/8 of it, etc. This only works if removing / adding data is relatively easy.

Comment: You nailed the problem on the head in your last sentence.  The input file gets heavily manipulated into the data being put into the tree and eventually the vector.  There's not really any way for me to eliminate any set amount from the final data set without doing some serious hacking to just throw out stuff well after data has been read in.  Certainly a good suggestion in simpler cases though.  Thanks for the continued help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to try to determine approximately which line of your code does causes the crash.

Since this only happen outside your IDE you can use `OutputDebugString` to output the current position, and use DebugView.

Really the behavior of a program compiled for debug inside and outside of IDE can be completely different. They can use a different set of runtime libraries when a program is loaded from the IDE.

Recently I was bitten by a timing bug in my code, somehow when debugging from the IDE the timing was always good an the bug  was not observed, but in release mode bam the bug was there. This kinda of bug are really a PITA to debug.