# Why is C++ fwrite() producing larger output in release?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I recently wrote an implementation of the Canonical Huffman compression algorithm. I have a 500kb test file that can be compressed to about 250kb when running the debug and release builds from within Visual Studio 2008. However when I run the release build straight from the executeable the test file only compresses to about 330kb.

I am assuming that something is going wrong when the file is written using fwrite(). I have tested the program and confirmed that uncompressing the files always produces the correct uncompressed file.

Does anyone know why this could possibly be? How could the same executeable file be producing different sized outputs based on where it is launched from?

Comment: You're probably going to have to break this down into a smaller question.  How can you be sure that fwrite is doing something different?  Because you're doing compression, do both files uncompress equally?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the files to see what is different?

Comment: Are both versions of the file valid ?

Comment: I have tested it quite thoroughly. I have run the program in both release and debug inside and outside of the IDE. In all situations if I compress the file, and then uncompress it the file uncompressed files are equal. Only when I run the release build outside of the IDE do I get a compressed file that is larger than it should be.

After reviewing the compressed files, the one produced by the release build outside of the IDE is very different to all the others, the characters written are different and the amount of characters written is far greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it through [App Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en) and see what it finds.

Comment: Thanks so much, I quickly ran the AppVerifier and I am getting an access violation somewhere. So that gives me a starting point.

Comment: Turns out there was an array out of bounds read happening, surprised is wasn't caught by the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an uninitialized value somewhere. See also:
[Program crashes when run outside IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907812/program-crashes-when-run-outside-ide)

Running in IDE will initialize values to global defaults, running outside IDE doesn't, so any uninit'd variables will have different values.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the the [/RTCu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28VS.71%29.aspx) compiler option to help detect use of uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using that compiler flag but I didn't receive any new information regarding uninitialised variables.